# Save social login data in a existing user

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using email as my username therefore email has an unique propertie. Problem is there will be cases that an existing user has attempted to social login and then allauth receives a integrity database error.

Goal is, to change the behavior and instead of attempt to create a new user, use the existing user for saving related social stuff. To achieve that, I'm extending the Default Social Account Adapter, although it's not working properly yet.

```
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
    """
    Save a newly signed up social login.

    In case of auto-signup, the signup form is not available.
    """
    existing_user = User.objects.filter(email=sociallogin.user.email).first()

    if existing_user:
        sociallogin.user = existing_user
        u = existing_user
    else:
        u = sociallogin.user
        u.set_unusable_password()

    if form:
        get_account_adapter().save_user(request, u, form)
    else:
        get_account_adapter().populate_username(request, u)
    sociallogin.save(request)

    return u
```